# Swift 2.2 enumerateObjectsUsingBlock - stop

Tags: ios, swift

Prior to Swift 2.2 I could stop an enumeration by making the stop parameter mutable with var and then setting it appropriately`stop = UnsafeMutablePointer<ObjCBool>.alloc(NSNumber(bool: true).integerValue)`

Now in 2.2 making a parameter mutable is deprecated so how do I stop an enumeration?

Comment: I cannot test it currently, but `stop.memory = true` should work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your syntax is pretty weird ;-)

This works in both Swift 2.1 and 2.2

```
let array: NSArray = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
array.enumerateObjectsUsingBlock { (object, idx, stop) in
  print(idx)
  if idx == 3 {
    stop.memory = true
  }
}
```

**Swift 3:**

```
let array: NSArray = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
array.enumerateObjects({ (object, idx, stop) in
    print(idx)
    if idx == 3 {
        stop.pointee = true
    }
})
```

Nevertheless – as suggested in the other answer – use native Swift `Array`.

Comment: In 2.2 I believe both inout and var are deprecated. Your answer is correct though. Its making me wait 2 minutes to mark it as so far some reason haha.

Comment: `inout` is not deprecated in Swift 2.2

Comment: You last remark is (in my opinion) misleading. Pointers are not inout parameters, and even a UnsafeMutablePointer is a value type and not necessarily mutable. The reason that `stop.memory = true` works is that the `memory` property of `UnsafeMutablePointer` is marked as `{ get nonmutating set }`, which means that setting the `memory` property is not considered a mutation of the pointer value.

Comment: Why `initialize(to:)` in Swift 3? Why not `stop.pointee = true`?

Comment: @Sulthan I didn't that particular edit but updated the answer with the proper Swift 3 code

Answer (score 0):

You should uses the tools Swift offers instead:

```
for (idx, value) in array.enumerate(){
    print(idx)
    if idx == 10 { break }
}
```

---

As you clarified in your comment, that you are enumerating a PHFetchResult, use following extensions to enable swift enumeration:

```
extension PHFetchResult: SequenceType {
    public func generate() -> NSFastGenerator {
        return NSFastGenerator(self)
    }
}
```

---

```
let fetchOptions = PHFetchOptions()
fetchOptions.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "creationDate", ascending: true)]

let allPhotos = PHAsset.fetchAssetsWithOptions(fetchOptions)

for (idx, photoAsset) in allPhotos.enumerate() {
    if idx == 2 { break }
    print("\(idx) \(photoAsset)")
}
```

Results in:

```
0 <PHAsset: 0x7fa0d9f29c40> B84E8479-475C-4727-A4A4-B77AA9980897/L0/001 mediaType=1/0, sourceType=1, (4288x2848), creationDate=2009-10-09 21:09:20 +0000, location=0, hidden=0, favorite=0 
1 <PHAsset: 0x7fa0d9f29df0> 106E99A1-4F6A-45A2-B320-B0AD4A8E8473/L0/001 mediaType=1/0, sourceType=1, (4288x2848), creationDate=2011-03-13 00:17:25 +0000, location=1, hidden=0, favorite=0
```

Comment: I'm enumerating over a PHFetchResult which does not conform to sequence type

Comment: @RichmondWatkins: see my edit for a 3-line extension to enumerate PFFetchResult in a swifty way.